# Using Firebug to send form data

Tags: ajax, debugging, firebug

Is it possible to send AJAX data with params, that aren't in the URL?
I have a script that gets information from a form, and the server uses POST and not GET.

I noticed the possibility in FireBug to send the params only in the URL.

In case it's impossible, is there another program that might help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have also a look at [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

Answer (score 3):

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3899

Simple and FireFoxy..

Answer (score 1):

For that I use [LiveHTTPHeader addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/3829). It offers you nice record/replay facilities and replay also for HTTP POST style. You can also modify the payload.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible.
In XMLHttpRequest.send(); you can put POST data